# Continuity of the joint CDF

Tags: probability, distributions, continuous-data

Consider two random variables $(X,Y)$. Suppose that the joint cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $(X,Y)$ is continuous. Is it true that this implies:

1) The CDF of $X$ is continuous?

2) The CDF of $X+Y$ is continuous?

I believe that 1) is correct. I'm not sure about 2) but I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag. For 2), consider the case when $X$ is continuous and $Y=-X$.

Comment: @Xi'an But then would the joint CDF be considered to be a continuous function?